# ECOFF & MIPS PECOFF same

Tags: c, coff

I am trying to understand different Object file formats and was able to get the required information for COFF, XCOFF and other file formats. However i couldnt find much information on net for ECOFF.

I think, ECOFF is MIPS version of PECOFF. Not sure though. Need clarity on this. Would some one please clarify? Tried google, but no much/clear information.

Where can i get additional information related to source, its file header structure, data section information, relocation info, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete specifications for [ECOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECOFF) in the ECOFF [Object File / Symbol Table Format Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305114748/http://h41361.www4.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V50A_ACRO_SUP/OBJSPEC.PDF)

Comment: Thanks Hasturkun. Running through this document. Another question: This document is from HP. SO is ECOFF, registed to HP?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, really. Presumably they now own the copyright on the specification. I don't know what it being registered to HP or not would entail.